# How do you create Expression<Func<T, T>> given the property names of T to map?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, expression

Here's what the required function would look like:

```
 public static Expression<Func<T, T>> GetExpression<T>(string propertyNames) where T : class
 {
       var properties = propertyNames.Split(
            new char[] { ',' }, 
            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
        ).ToList();

       //need help here
 }
```

Currently I'm doing it like this:

```
_context.Questions.Select(q => 
                new Question() {
                    QuestionId = q.QuestionId,
                    QuestionEnglish = q.QuestionEnglish
                }
).ToList();
```

And I want to replace it with:

```
_context.Questions.Select(GetExpression<Question>("QuestionId, QuestionInEnglish")).ToList();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think that would be an improvement. Look into AutoMapper or something.

Comment: Explicit string property names are a recipe for refactoring desaster. If you are tired of manually writing the projection each time, store the projection somewhere or use automapper as AluanHaddad suggested. However, maybe you should just disable proxy creation and query `_context.Questions.AsNoTracking()...` instead of projecting your result to its own type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this;

```
    public static Func<T, T> GetExpression<T>(string propertyNames)
    {
        var xParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "parameter");

        var xNew = Expression.New(typeof(T));

        var selectFields = propertyNames.Split(',').Select(parameter => parameter.Trim())
            .Select(parameter => {

                    var prop = typeof(T).GetProperty(parameter);

                    if (prop == null) // The field doesn't exist
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                    var xOriginal = Expression.Property(xParameter, prop);

                    return Expression.Bind(prop, xOriginal);
                }
            ).Where(x => x != null);

        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T>>(Expression.MemberInit(xNew, selectFields), xParameter);

        return lambda.Compile();
    }
```

Usage;

```
    var list = new List<Question>{new Question{QuestionEnglish = "QuestionName",QuestionId = 1}};
    var result = list.Select(GetExpression<Question>("QuestionId, QuestionEnglish"));
```

Comment: Since I needed the expression itself i.e., Expression<Func<T, T>>, I had to remove the Compile method call. Everything else works like it should. Thank you!